# InfoPath 2010 - People picker not working/opening in filler

Tags: infopath, people-picker

For some reason, people picker is not working in the InfoPath 2010 filler or Preview.

When I publish the form as a "web enabled form", the People Picker will open up in the browser and it works fine, but when I publish the same form without web enabled and it opens up in the InfoPath filler... the people picker does not work at all. **Nothing** happens when I click the directory or "check" button.

Has anyone else run into this problem or know why this might be happening??

Comment: Seems to be a common problem with no answers. Various solutions propose hacking SharePoint files or require access to the Admin settings of SharePoint, neither of which are doable by the average person.